# How to install gfortran-7 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, gfortran

I have a code written in FORTRAN 77 that only runs with **gfortran 7**. I was able to install gfortran 7 on my old computer under Ubuntu 20.04 with *sudo apt install gfortran-7*. Now I have a new computer under **Ubuntu 22.04** and this command does not work anymore : *E: Unable to locate package gfortran-7*.

Is there a way to install gfortran-7 on Ubuntu 22.04 ?

Comment: Maybe you can try posting here: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Have you tried it with a more modern version of gfortran? Why do you think it is specifically gfortran-7 that has to be used?

Comment: For an old F77 code it is very unlikely that a more recent version of gfortran would not compile it. Just use the `gfortran` command. If there are any issues, you are welcome to ask about them.

Comment: I agree with @VladimirFГероямслава . There exist tons of legacy F77 code around that smoothly compile with the most recent compilers. There can be some problems with codes that were using non-standard/non-portable features, but if gfortran-7 was compiling it, it's unlikely that a more recent version doesn't. Maybe some compiler options are now required, but you have to show which compilation errors you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need for some reason that specific version which is no longer supported since Nov. 2019, you can try to build it from sources following the instructions on this page: https://gcc.gnu.org/git.html

Otherwise, you should install one of the versions available in the official repositories of Ubuntu 22.04:

- gfortran-9 (9.4.0)
- gfortran-10 (10.3.0)
- gfortran-11 (11.2.0)
- gfortran-12 (12.1.0)

By default, gfortran stands for gfortran-11:

```
$ sudo apt install gfortran
```

Installing gfortran-12 may be interesting if there are new features that you need, or if it increases performances.
Installing an older version may be interesting because they may have less bugs: 9.4.0 will have less bugs than the fresh 12.1.0.
In fact, concerning performances, it depends on your code. You may install the four versions and benchmark them with your programs. A newer version may be faster... or not...

Note that the release year of those four versions can be obtained by adding 10 to the major version: gfortran-9 was initially released in 2019 and gfortran-12 in 2022.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was *"Is there a way to install gfortran-7 on Ubuntu 22.04 ?"*

Comment: Answer updated with the official instructions to access gfortran source code from git

Comment: I think that for a beginner it is usually easier to compile one of the snapshots. At least that is the way I always took. Then the script for the prereqisities comes handy. Usually I install a more recent version to an old OS, though so other complications with some missing or obsolete build tools may happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can install older versions of gfortran (eg., gfortran-7 or higher) in Zorin Linux. The zorin package repository contains older gfortran versions. So install zorin linux and install gfortran as "sudo apt install gfortran-7". Latest ubuntu does not contain gfortran-7 but zorin, which uses ubuntu packages, contains gfortran-7. I dont know why.

Comment: Changing the Linux distribution to one containing some old GCC version sounds really extreme. Compiling a GCC version snapshot is not hard.

Comment: Yes, it may not be the correct way of solving this issue but if nothing works I feel this is the only option. Zorin is a popular linux OS and it has all the functionalities as in any other Ubuntu based linux. The gfortran-7 is available even in the latest version of zorin 16.3. I have a big program that works only with gfortran 7. Editing the code to suit newer gfortran is a headache. So I am very much thankful to zorin as no other distribution has this.

Comment: I am saying that you can easily install GCC 7 anywhere, even in latest Ubuntu or Redhat or Arch or whatever. BTW OpenSUSE 15.4 also has GCC 7.

Comment: Can you please show me how to install GCC 7? When I tried to install it, it prompted me to install many dependency packages which was a headache.

Comment: Download one of the snapshots, extract and follow https://gcc.gnu.org/install/ Note the "You may simply run the contrib/download_prerequisites script in the GCC source directory to set up everything." point.